# Place multiple toggle buttons inside <select> as options in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, toggle

As shown in the below image, In my Agular project I want to create a UI which is having **toggles buttons inside a dropdown**. I tried by adding  field inside  and  but its not working.

```
  <select name="samples" id="sample">
    <option value="sample1"><input type="checkbox" id="sample1" name="sample1" value="Sample1"></option>
  </select>
```

Can someone help me to make this in the best way?

[image]

Comment: "I tried by adding field inside" — show it then

Comment: You can't do that in pure html select option. But  you have another option, you create your own dropdown and you can customize it.

Comment: Hi @TitusSutioFanpula. Yes, I have created a custom component to achieve this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The best option was to create a custom dropdown component and reuse it in the Parent Component.